# Postgresql Full Outer Join 2 Tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, outer-join

Table structure:

`tb_participante_respuesta`

```
ID | n_varcod | n_parcod | c_resval 
1  |   48     |    1     |   'PRT' 
2  |   48     |    2     |   'ZDE'
```

`tb_encuesta_valor`

```
ID | n_varcod | c_valnom | n_valord
1  |   48     |   'ART'  |    1
2  |   48     |   'PRT'  |    2
3  |   48     |   'ZDE'  |    3
```

I execute this query:

```
select a.n_parcod,b.c_valnom ,a.c_resval
from tb_participante_respuesta a
full outer join tb_encuesta_valor b on b.n_varcod=a.n_varcod
                                   and b.c_valnom=a.c_resval
where b.n_varcod=48
order by b.n_valord;
```

The output:

```
n_parcod | c_valnom | c_resval
  Null   |   'ART'  |  Null
    1    |   'PRT'  |  'PRT'
  Null   |   'ZDE'  |  Null
```

I want something like this:

```
n_parcod | c_valnom | c_resval
     1   |   'ART'  |  Null
     1   |   'PRT'  |  'PRT'
     1   |   'ZDE'  |  Null
     2   |   'ART'  |  Null
     2   |   'PRT'  |  Null
     2   |   'ZDE'  |  'ZDE'
```

Comment: No pg version, no explanation, ambiguous data, broken format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cross join` will do a cartesian product. Then you need to check the match criteria separately.

```
select
    p.n_parcod,
    e.c_valnom,
    case when 
            p.c_resval = e.c_valnom and 
            e.n_varcod = p.n_varcod 
        then p.c_resval 
    end as c_resval
from
    tb_encuesta_valor e
        cross join
    tb_participante_respuesta p
where
    e.n_varcod = 48
order by
    p.n_parcod, 
    e.n_valord;
```

[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ac4c4/2)

Comment: Thanks, i didnt know about cross join.